# How to make the grails 2 documentation quit generating a horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Anyone out there still working with grails 2 applications, and noticed how the documentation on

https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.6/guide/single.html

https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.5/guide/single.html

https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.3.11/guide/single.html

Require the use of a horizontal scroll bar and the Quick Reference Links are way off the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by some really wide `<pre>` tags in the documentation.

In Chrome you can fix this with a bookmarklet.

Create a new bookmark with the following URL:

```
javascript:(function() {var sheet=document.createElement('style');sheet.innerHTML="pre{white-space:pre-wrap}";document.body.appendChild(sheet)}())
```

Here it is again formatted, but you will need to paste it as a one-liner.

```
javascript:(function() {
    var sheet=document.createElement('style');
    sheet.innerHTML="pre{white-space:pre-wrap}"; 
    document.body.appendChild(sheet)
 }())
```

[image]

Next time you visit one of those pages, just click the bookmark and a second or so later you will get your Quick Reference to be quick again and no more horizontal scrolling.